Get glue job run details
I am stuck at this issue since long. My desired output is to run a glue job, inside the glue job I want to fetch glue job run end time of the run that was started right now. Is there any way to print end time and error in cloud metrics?
I tried it using get_job_run api but it is only giving me run start time, I am not able to fetch end time of the run. Please help me out

Unfortunately, you can't fetch the endtime in the same glue job while it's running.
You can use system time to log the current time at the end of the job or use the AWS Glue JobRun API to fetch those details separately once job is completed.
Example:
response = client.get_job_run(
    JobName='string',
    RunId='string',
    PredecessorsIncluded=True|False
)

Endtime can be captured by CompletedOn object and error messages can be captured under ErrorMessage in the response output.
Related Question : How to get Start and End time in a Job AWS Glue?
Helpful links: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue/client/get_job_run.html
